Science fiction film about two brother, one of which is sick and other healthy
Okay so I'm pretty sure it was in the future. There were brothers and one was in good health and the other was sickly.
The sickly one wanted to go on some space mission or something, I honestly can't remember, so some guy in a wheelchair helped him concoct some plan using his healthy blood and a bunch of other stuff, honestly, my memory of it is so bad but I swear there was like, a body transplant of some sort.
Anyway the brothers face off in some sort of swimming competition. The healthy brother always won, but the last time they did this,  the time the sickly one won instead.
I know this is a mess but this is all I really remember. Pretty tragic movie.

Did you mean to say (but this time the sickly one died) ?

@Ahmad no. The sickly one won that time.

It's Gattaca, the 1997 movie about genetic engineering based discrimination.

A genetically inferior man assumes the identity of a superior one in order to pursue his lifelong dream of space travel.

Key points, the sickly one is Vincent Freeman (Ethan Hawke), a "in-valid" child born without genetic engineering, in a society that has embraced Eugenics and discriminates against the genetically weak. He's not really sickly, he's just treated like that because he wasn't engineered to be perfect. His young brother, Anton was engineered, as a Valid.
They swim to compete against each other. Anton, as genetically bred for strength, tends to win. The last time, decades before when they were still children, Vincent's urge to win overcame his mental limit, while Anton's mental limit caused him to almost drown.
Jerome Eugene Morrow (Jude Law), having suffered an accident that rendered him a paraplegic, allows Vincent to use his blood, hair, and other genetic markers, so that Vincent can go into the space program.
